# Check if div has a specific style applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my website if the page is first loaded and it's maximized/fullscreen, the div `comBrand` has the particular CSS properties I want applied.

During a resize event I apply different properties to that element using the `.css()` function so that the div doesn't overlap with other screen items, however, instead of actually changing the CSS it appears to add a style attribute to that div in the code. Sometimes depending on how you resize the page, the resize function might have ended in such a way that when you use the maximize button, you end up the incorrect placement of the particular div. I am checking for a few things to make sure that doesn't happen.

However, I don't know if the syntax here is correct for checking the style attribute of a div during the resize function because it doesn't seem to work as expected.

```
$(window).resize(function() {

//first check
  if ( $('#comBrand').css('top') == '155px')
  {
   //second check to see if the peculiuar event was reached where the div is positioned incorrectly but the window isn't maximized
    if ( ($('#comBrand').attr('style') == 'top: 155px;margin-left: -615px;left: 50%;') && (window.screen.width > window.screen.availWidth))
    {
    $('#comBrand').css({'top': '155px', 'margin-left': '-615px', 'left': '50%'});
    }
    else //assume that the page is already maximized and adjust the div accordingly
    {
    $('#comBrand').css({'top': '141px', 'margin-left': '0', 'left': '0'});
    }
  }
  else //default else, if the CSS of the div is anything other than what was initially checked for, set it back to its default location
  {
  $('#comBrand').css({'top': '155px', 'margin-left': '-615px', 'left': '50%'});
  }

});
```

I know it's a little confusing and somewhat of a hack but I'd still like to get it to function.

I added two classes, and gave the div comBrand the class of maximized hard coded in the html, and then used this code in the resize function, however, it doesn't work or do anything...

```
$(window).resize(function() {   

  if ($('#comBrand').hasClass('maximized'))
        {
        $('#comBrand').removeClass('maximized');
        $('#comBrand').addClass('minimized');
        }

  else {
       $('#comBrand').removeClass('minimized');
       $('#comBrand').addClass('maximized');
  } 

});
```

Comment: `During a resize event I apply different properties to that element using the .css() function` would be interesting to see that part. Have you considered using Media Queries? Why you check for `if ( $('#comBrand').css('top') == '155px')` instead of a particular window width? Also you use this logic: `if === 155` else `$('#comBrand').css({'top': '155px',` makes no sense to me... It's pretty hard to understand whant you actually need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Apul Gupta pointed out, you should be adding and removing classes.  So, set up a couple classes:

CSS:

```
.FirstClass
{
top: 155px;
margin-left -615px;
left:50%;
}
.SecondClass
{
top:141px;
margin-left:0;
left:0;
}
```

Next, change your logic to this:

```
    if (!$('#comBrand').hasClass('FirstClass') && (window.screen.width > window.screen.availWidth)){
        $('#comBrand').removeClass("FirstClass");
        $("#comBrand").addClass("SecondClass");
        }
  }
  else {
       $("#comBrand").removeClass("SecondClass");
       $("comBrand").addClass("FirstClass");
  }
```

Your first nested if statement doesn't do anything...You were checking to see if the CSS was X - and if so, you were setting the CSS to X.  So, I removed that code.

I must admit your if/else logic is unoptimized(a bit redundant) and confusing, but this should give you an idea of what you need to do.

Comment: I already got this far but the code isn't doing anything...see edited question.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Now that I'm using classes, the code for the has class and remove add and add class..none of its working now. Nothing changes or gets added or removed.

Comment: If that's the case, put an alert inside your window.resize function to see if it's getting called.  Also, the llogic that you currently have in your edited question would switch the class every time the window is resized, irrespective of everything else.  I'm guessing that's not what you're trying to do, but from your question I can't figure out what you're trying to accomplish.  Your question was titled 'check if a div has a specific style applied' and that's what I was trying to answer.

Comment: Well, at this point before I do anything else I'm just trying to get it to re-apply the minimized and maximized classes with the simple check. It SHOULD be doing something just because I gave the id comBrand the class maximized in the html, but the check for "hasClass" doesn't seem to do jack.

Comment: Did you put all of your JavaScript inside the $("document").ready(function(){}); block?  If "hasClass" isn't working, your problem isn't your code (unless you have other syntax errors that are breaking everything), it's your references and/or timing.  Did you try putting an alert in there like I suggested?

Comment: Nevermind, it seems to be working now, I added an s to the http of the link to the jquery source, which I didn't seem to need before, and now it works.

Answer (score 4):

You should add a CSS `class` instead of using CSS properties individually. And after that just check using `.hasClass` to find if class added.

Read More here:

http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/

http://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: I'm not adding styles individually I googled around looking up how to change the CSS of a div, that div comBrand has its own set of properties...i'm not applying styles individually. When I just the jQuery to modify the css it's applying the style, as said before, instead of actually modifying the css properties directly..

Comment: You're definitely modifying the styles, individually.  That is what the code that you posted is doing.  Adding or removing classes is a distinctly different approach - one that is almost always superior, especially if you're going to be reusing the CSS.

Comment: But try my answer out.

Answer (score 2):

While Apul's answer is definitely correct, it doesn't answer the question asked. To do this, you could do the following:

```
var styles = $('#myDiv').attr('style').split(';');
var stylesKeyValue = {};
styles.forEach(function(value) {
    stylesKeyValue[value.split(':')[0]] = value.split(':')[1];
});
```

This would work with something like:

```
<div id="myDiv" style="background-color:pink;min-height:20px;"></div>
```

and then you could test values with:

```
console.log(stylesKeyValue['background-color'] == 'pink');
```

Comment: +1 I was wondering when someone would actually answer what was asked. I of course tried looking it up on my own earlier but when people ask about styles everyone automatically assumes CSS instead of the style attribute. I also think it's misleading that the CSS function is called CSS yet applies a style attribute to an id. Oh well.

Comment: @ChristopherBruce Please note, I was only adding the answer here if for some reason classes don't work. They truly are the best solution to the question... just not the precise answer.

Comment: I understand, the classes do make it easier and I agree are a better solution, but sometimes it can be frustrating when you've worked on something for a while and just want an answer to the problem at hand instead of taking a different approach. Psychological, I guess :)

Comment: @ChristopherBruce, just a heads up, this came up in another question I was working with, and remembered I made the same mistake here. I changed prop('style') to attr('style') since prop will return the actual css properties, and not the literal string.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at this bit, as I'm not sure you can guarantee the format of that string. At the least, you should be comparing individual fields with `.css('')`.

```
$('#comBrand').attr('style') == 'top: 155px;margin-left: -615px;left: 50%;'
```

But as the others have suggested, I'd advocate using CSS classes instead of the style attribute.